# Mongodb: What does a dollar sign (.$.) in a JSON key do?

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to change the strength based on the hero name in a document like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("52b0d27b5dee463864000001"),
"author" : "niko",
"permalink" : "super_heroes" 
"hero" : [
    {
        "name" : "Batman",
        "strength" : 1,
        "magic" : [ ],
        "times" : [ ]
    },
```

I couldn't change it when initially trying:

```
var operator = { '$set' : { 'hero.strength' : strength } }; 

var query = { 'permalink': permalink , 'hero.name':name };
posts.update(query, operator, options, function(err, numModified) {...})
```

I got `MongoError: can't append to array using string field name: strength`.

But after seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040344/cant-append-to-array-using-string-field-name-when-performing-update-on-arra) I added a dollar sign and it worked:

```
var operator = { '$set' : { 'hero.$.strength' : strength } };
```

What did that dollar sign in a JSON key do?  I tried googling it, but I just came up with a million explanations of what jQuery is.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a JSON operator (there is no such things as JSON operator. You might think that JSON is a string).

In this context $ is a [mongodb positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to perform update in a specific position.